# How to find exact HTC One S version (S3/S4)

Tags: hardware, htc-one-s

I have begun doing research about rooting my HTC One S phone (HTC Sense looks so nice but unfortunately is so unstable) and one of the first things I've noticed is that [there are two versions of HTC One S](http://androidforums.com/one-s-all-things-root/597701-htc-one-s-has-two-versions-s3-s4.html). One has a 1.5gHz dual core CPU, the other has a 1.7gHz dual core CPU.

I went through all the information I could find in my phone's "about" menu, but the CPU section only specifies "dual core". The packaging also has no further details than this.

The **only** reference I have is that the (online) shop I bought it at, has 1.5gHz in the spec. That would mean I have the S4 which is the most common version. But the vendor may as well get that information from somewhere else rather than the actual product, so I want to be sure before doing anything.

I've already searched google and can't find anything, but I hardly know what to look for either. Seems like no other website knows of this distinction.

On a side note, if anyone knows (has experience with) any good and reliable guides about rooting the HTC One S, feel free to post them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way. Check your packaging. Look for Model describtion on the back of the other label. Either z520 or z560, the z520 is S4, 560 is S3.

from wikipedia:

Processor and memory

One version of the One S uses a Qualcomm Snapdragon S4...In certain markets the One S uses the older Snapdragon S3... The two versions have slightly different packaging, the S4 is model Z520e/Z520m and states "Processor: Dual Core, 1.5GHz"/"CPU Speed 1.5 GHZ, dual core, whereas the S3 is model Z560e and states "Processor: Dual Core".